# Bad Access when using OpenCV in iOS 11

Tags: c++, iphone, swift, opencv, ios11

when I use opencv2 in iOS 11 I get a `Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x183ae4ee0)` crash as soon as I run any function under `cv::` namespace, like `equalizeHist` or `threshold`. I am able to convert my images to `cv::Mat` and these Matrices back to `UIImage`, so there should be no issue about the images itself.

I did include `opencv2.framework` in "Linked Frameworks and Libraries". I disabled bitcode, using libc++ (LLVM C++) Standard Library and GNU++14 C++ Language Dialect.

I am doing all of this in Obj-C in a class called OpenCVWrapper. This class is then used in Swift using a Bridging Header.

All of the code is executed on the main thread.

Is there anything I'm missing to make this run properly?

Comment: Where did you get the opencv2.framework?

Comment: I did get it from the official website.